# Android Error: Notify user of what file is being downloaded

Tags: android, android-asynctask, download

I have a code that downloads videos from a URL. I am using AsyncTask. Now, what I want to do is notify the user via progress dialog of what video is being downloaded, or something like "Downloading Video 2 of 10". I am using the following code:

```
//DOWNLOAD VIDEOS
private class downloadVideosAsync extends AsyncTask <String, String, String>{

    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        MyActivity.this.mProgressDialog.setMessage("Downloading Videos...");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings){
        try{

            ArrayList<String> VideoNames = VideosM.getVideoNames();
            ArrayList<String> VideoUrls = VideosM.getVideoUrls();

            File vidFile = null;
            int videoNamesLenght = VideoNames.size();
            int x;

            for(x = 0; x < videoNamesLenght; x++) {

                //download video
                String[] videoName = VideoNames.get(x).split("/");
                String currentFile = videoName[0] + "." + videoName[1];
                String currentFileURL = VideoUrls.get(x) + VideoNames.get(x);

                vidFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() 
                                    + "/Engagia/Downloads/Videos/", currentFile);

                if( !vidFile.exists() ){
                    int curr_vid = x + 1;

                    String ui_msg = "Downloading Videos " + curr_vid + " of " + videoNamesLenght + "...";
                    MyActivity.this.mProgressDialog.setMessage( ui_msg );

                    VideosC.downloadVideoFile(currentFile, currentFileURL, vidFile);

                }
            }

        }catch (NullPointerException e){
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String lenghtOfFile) {
        new downloadSlideshowsAsync().execute();
    }
}
```

The code above give me an error:

**android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.**

EDIT:

I also tried:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {

        String ui_msg = "Downloading Videos " + curr_vid + " of " + videoNamesLenght + "...";
        Engagia.this.mProgressDialog.setMessage( ui_msg );
        Log.v("VideosController.java", ui_msg );

    }
});
```

but gives me the same error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only a special thread, often called the "UI thread", can modify UI elements.  You can have specific code run on the UI thread by running things inside the `runOnUiThread` function that's part of [Activity class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).  For example:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
    // ...
    }
});
```

Comment: Oh man, it works, I just had to remove MyActivity.this.mProgressDialog.setMessage( "Inside video loop." ); after the for(x = 0; x < videoNamesLenght; x++) here at my end. My bad. again thanks!

Answer (score 2):

use onProgreesUpdate to update the the progress bar.

find the details on the android developer site [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)